# Поиск самого продолжительного тренда без циклов

Tags: python

Можно ли решить следующую задачу по поиску самого продолжительного тренда без циклов?

Написать программу trend.py, которая получает в виде строки набор целых чисел разделенных пробелами, вычисляет самый продолжительных тренд из этих чисел и выводит его на экран.

Тренд в данной задаче — это возрастающая или убывающая последовательность чисел (включая повторяющиеся значения).

Исходя из определения, в одной последовательности чисел может быть несколько трендов, а также одно и то же число может попадать сразу в два тренда. Например, из последовательности 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 можно выделить два тренда 1 2 3 4 4 и 4 4 3 2 — четверки попадают сразу в оба тренда. Нам нужно получить самую продолжительную (длинную) последовательность, то есть 1 2 3 4 4.

Если самых продолжительных трендов будет несколько, то нужно вывести первый.

Пример использования:

> python trend.py "1 2 3 4 4 3 2"
> 1 2 3 4 4

Comment: Рекурсией никак?

Comment: Может "без вложенных циклов"? Или "без явных циклов" т.е. через функциями splitt, map, [:], ... , содержащие цикл внутри?